# Redirect when the user uses IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I created this Custom Route Class in ASP.NET MVC:

```
public class UserAgentConstraint:IRouteConstraint {
  private string RequiredUserAgent;
  public UserAgentConstraint(string agentParam) {
    RequiredUserAgent = agentParam;
  }
  public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName,
    RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection) {
    return httpContext.Request.UserAgent != null && !httpContext.Request.UserAgent.Contains(RequiredUserAgent);
  }
}
```

And in Global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
  routes.MapRoute("myRoute2", "{controller}/{action}/{Id}",
    new { controller = "home", action = "index", Id = UrlParameter.Optional }, new {
      customConstriant=new UserAgentConstraint("IE")
    }
  }
```

The above code works prefectly, but when the user uses IE, I get a 404 Error. I want to redirect to a custom Page. I dont want to use a Custom Error in the `Web.Config` file because my error is only for use in IE. How can one do this?

Thanks in your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a better way of doing this is using ActionFilter.

```
    public class BrowserFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute 
    {
        public string [] _browserNames { get; set; }
        public AssetIdFilterAttribute(params string [] browserNames)
        {
            _browserNames= browserNames;
        }


        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {            
            //get browser name from somewhere
            string currentBrowser  = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.Browser;
            if(_browserNames.Contains(currentBrowser))
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("your URL");
        }

    }
```

you can apply it in Controller level like this :

```
  [BrowserFilter("IE","Opera","SomeOtherBrowser")]
  public class BrowserAwareController() : Controller
  {

  }
```

hope this help.good luck.